# App crashing on using camera - Capacitor on Android 12 , 13

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

**Explanation of Problem:**

App crashes and restarts when taking and confirming a picture on Android 12 and 13.
[App crashes on clicking this button after taking picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMvmY.jpg)

We are using `Capacitor` camera plugin. When capturing an image with the camera plugin it crashes everytime I take a picture and the app restarts.

This only happens on Android 12 and 13. It works perfectly fine on Android less than 12. I can't find any exceptions when debugging on a mobile device because debugging is killed as soon as an image is captured and then once the image captured is confirmed it restarts the application.

> Capacitor ver: 4.2.0
> minsdkversion: 22
> compilesdkversion: 33
> targetsdkversion: 33

**Tried Solutions**
We tried different open source Cordova plugins but nothing worked as all of them have not been updated since 2021. Please help us resolve this issue.

**Edit 1:** Sharing the code.

```
 import { Plugins, CameraResultType, CameraSource } from '@capacitor/core';

const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
        quality: 100,
        resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
        source: CameraSource.Camera,
      });
      this.imageUrl = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image.base64String;
```

After we click the `tick` icon, we get the base64 code in the `imageUrl` variable.

Comment: Care to share some code? For example where you use Camera.getPhoto etc.?

Comment: Hii, I have edited the question and added the code as requested. Please have a look and let me know if you need anything else

Comment: You're setting the result type as base64, but try with: `resultType: CameraResultType.Uri`. Your image url is then: `image.webPath`

Comment: We need base64 to pass to php, same code works for Android less than 12

Comment: Are you added permission ??